# Will there be a sequel to "The Last Magician" by Lisa Maxwell?

Tags: books, sequel, the-last-magician

I just finished reading "The Last Magician" by Lisa Maxwell and I was wondering if there has been any announcement regarding a sequel.  Not only did the book end at a cliff hanger, but it seemed like it was leaving room for questions to be answered in a second book.

Comment: I found a mention on goodreads that there will be, and it seems kinda obvious there would if that's how it ends, but I cannot find any direct word of a sequel.  Possibly waiting on a deal/announcement, but it seems inevitable given that the book definitely looks like a successful one.

Comment: Is that a book just published last month?  Maybe she will write more only if it sells well...  or something....

Comment: The Kirkus review describes this as a "series opener" so it seems the expectation is that that story will continue in subsequent novels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

The author confirmed in an interview with FictionFare that she's "hard at work" on a sequel.

> **What’s next for you? Are you working on anything right now that you can tell us about?**
>
> *I am hard at work on the sequel for THE LAST MAGICIAN. I also have a dark little Middle Grade that I’m working on revisions to, so we can
> go out on submission with it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Blog Tour: The Last Magician by Lisa Maxwell](http://www.fictionfare.com/blog-tour-the-last-magician-by-lisa-maxwell/)</sup></sub>

And in this interview with TheRoyalPolarBear, that the two books are intended as a duology.

> **Are there any future plans to The Last Magician or at least to the sequel of the book? How many installments would there be?**
>
> *It is planned as a dualogy. But this is a great big story and a huge world, so I wouldn’t be opposed to writing more in this world.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview with Lisa Maxwell!](https://theroyalpolarbearreads.wordpress.com/)</sup></sub>

Apparently she's struggling with it a little...

> I’ve been really struggling with getting words for TLM’s sequel. I’m
> SO proud and happy with how TLM turned out, and part of me has been
> psyching myself out about being able to make the sequel better. Then,
> for some of these blog stops, I had to come up with deleted scenes and
> I found the first drafts of TLM’s opening. I’d forgotten that I’d
> started it as a first-person book. I’d forgotten how bad that first
> draft was. That’s helped some, because it lets me know that I can fix
> whatever I write, even if it does suck.
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview with Lisa Maxwell!](http://amagicalworldofwords.blogspot.co.uk/2017/08/blog-tour-for-last-magician-giveaway.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: FWIW there are currently [two sequels](https://www.goodreads.com/series/225910-the-last-magician) to this now so might be worth an update.

Answer (score 0):

A interview with her said she was hard at work making a sequel. It has a cover and a name, both of which she can't share yet

Comment: A link to the interview, and quotes from it, would greatly strengthen your answer. Also, you should have a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).